# So I dropped my external hdd is it dead?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, repair

I just dropped my external hdd ive seen drives that dont work after, and ones that work fine. I´ve never seen one that is recognized and even shows contents occasionally but i cant copy anything out of it or open anything.

Is this dead?

Any help woud be welcome.

[image]

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Can you run a SMART test?  [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: In addition to smart testing, you could have gotten a few bad sectors in the wrong place.  chkdsk /R f:    Wait for hours, and see if it finds any bad sectors.

Comment: I would wait with the chkdsk because it can damage things more than fix them. If your problem is the controller of the external harddrive, you may be able to rescue its data by simply opening the box, get the drive out and connect it to your computer by different means. The SMART test would definitely be the best thing to do first.

Answer (score 1):

Your hard drive is almost certainly damaged.  If there is any information of value on it, get another drive which is the same or larger size, and use (gnu) ddrescue to try and pull all the data off.   You may need to run this more then once, but DDRescue is good like this - it will remember what its already recovered.

If you value your data, DO NOT TRY RUN CHECKDISK/DISK REPAIRS on the damaged drive.  This is only going to make things worse.

If you are only able to read from the drive intermittently, and this starts to get "more intermittent", there are some "last ditch" things you can try, which sometimes work and sometimes make things worse - Try freezing the drive (make sure you put it in an airtight plastic bag first).  Sometimes the thermal contraction helps for a short while - the process may need to be repeated.   I've also heard of people heating the drive - I've not tried this, and its likely to be more destructive.

You should also run a S.M.A.R.T test to see what the drive thinks of itself to know if the drive thinks its dying.